# I would like to add amazon url link to to magento product catalog product listing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

How to add amazon url link to my product catalog listing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom product attribute for amazon link. Then assign that attribute to your attribute set. Then you can override listing template (list.phtml) in your theme to use amazon link instead of product link.

Comment: can  you help me that step to do the same as I am not so much savvy of magento. Earlier my website is handled by some agency. now I am handling my own. can you help me with print screen and guide how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

> Go to admin -> Stores -> Attributes -> Product

Click "**Add New Attribute**" button Set "**Attribute Code**" value "**amazon_link**" and "**Catalog Input Type for Store Owner**" value "**Text Field**", also complete all **mandatory field** and **save** attribute.

**Next step**

> Go to Stores -> Attributes -> Attribute

Set
Select **your product attribute group** and edit it.
You can newly add attribute under "**Unassigned Attributes**" section. Just drag and drop to "**Group**" section and save it.

**Next step**

> Go to Catalog -> Products

Edit your product and set value into "**amazon_link**" attribute and save it.

**Flush your Magento cache**

**Next step**

Override **list.phtml** file into your theme

Copy **list.phtml** file.

> Path:
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

to your theme

**Ex.** **app/design/frontend/theme_name_space/your_theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**

Open theme list.phtml file and find "**$block->getBlockHtml('formkey')**"
Put below code after that.

```
<?php
if ($_product->getAmazonLink()) {
    echo $_product->getAmazonLink();    
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for giving step wise. I have completed the first part but not finding the option of list.phtml . could you help me to find that option Vithal Bariya.

Comment: @RiteshThakur Make sure override file path is proper and also attribute value is not blank

Comment: Hi Vithal Bariya           I have created the link of product and showing buy button on magento product catalog page. But still its not redirect to Amazon. Can you help me with this issue.